# Rendering page using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I used a code similar to the code mentioned below in my app using React Router.

```
<Route path="/" handler={App}>
  <Route path="login" handler={LogIn}/>
</Route>
```

Suppose I have created a header field in App file like "Welcome to the page",it shows while running. But if I use another header for Log In page like "welcome to log in page",while running it shows like

```
Welcome to the page
Welcome to log in
```

means it attach new header with the previous page's. But I want to use the header differently. So, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `Login` component is mounted inside `App` component so everything in the `App` component will be always visible. Think about it as having box inside the box. The solution to that would be to:

1. if you're using version 0.13.x: make use of [`DefaultRoute` (check the example in the 0.13.x docs)](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/0.13.x/docs/guides/overview.md#with-react-router)
2. if you're using version 1.0.0-rc3: make use of [`IndexRoute`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#indexroute)

and then you just put your header in a new component which will be mounted when you hit `/` URL.

Your routes would look something like:

1. version 0.13.x:

```jsx
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
  <Route name="login" handler={Login}/>
  <DefaultRoute handler={Header}/>
</Route>
```

2. version 1.0.0-rc3:

```jsx
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Header} />
  <Route path="inbox" component={Login} />
</Route>
```

---

*Just as a side note as that would be probably your next question*:

React Router 1.0 provides very nice API for handling the authentication, I guess this is something you are trying to do. If that's the case, have a look at the [auth-flow example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow). And the [`onEnter`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replacestate).